# Wowza RTMP to RTSP

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, rtsp, rtmp, wowza

We're using a Raspicam to stream live video to a client using Wowza Streaming Engine. We use FFMPEG to encode and send to Wowza and we can succesfully watch the RTMP stream using JWPlayer. This is the FFMPEG command used:

```
ffmpeg -t 0 -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -b:v 250k -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast -f flv -r 15 rtmp://wowzaaddress:1935/live/live
```

To be able to watch the stream on mobile devices we want to use RTSP or HLS which Wowza provides links to, however when we use those links (provided on the Test Player) nothing happens and we can't even open them to test for example in VLC. We have already added the extra ports on our web server to see if that was the problem and still didn't work.
Does anybody know what the problem is or what could we be doing wrong?

Comment: What mobile devices have you tested, and what browser or player? When you curl the HLS URL, do you get a 200 response with the chunklist? In your [wowza-install-path]/logs/wowzastreamingengine_access.log file, do you see log lines that start with LiveStreamPacketizerCupertino related to your stream? When playing back the HLS links in VLC, what errors/messages do you see in the access log file?